# Could certain closed covering determine a coherent sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, coherent-sheaves

We know that a coherent sheaf on a scheme is determined by its restriction on certain open coverings (satisfying compatibility condition). Now I wonder how about a closed covering. To do so I started with simple cases on a smooth complex projective varieity $X$ of dimension $n$.

Taking $X$ itself to be the covering is trivial, so I want to start with coverings of smalll dimensions. Firstly I think about the closed points (covering of dimension zero), but they are not a covering; also coherent sheaf with same stalks can be different.

Then it comes to dimension one coverings: let $X$ a smooth projective variety which can be covered by lines. Given two coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ on $X$ such that
$$\iota^*_L\mathcal{F}\cong\iota^*_L\mathcal{G}$$
for any line $\iota_L:L\subset X$. What could one say about the relation between $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$?

I think we should have $\mathcal{F}\cong\mathcal{G}$ for $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ by the structure of $\textbf{Coh}(\mathbb{P}^n)$ (edited: no we do not, here I should write $\mathbb{P}^1$ because the vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^n$ are not necessarily decomposable).

What about the general case, for example a ruled surface?

I think such questions should be considered before. If so, any reference is welcome!

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  As Sasha wrote, this is false if $\mathcal{G}$ is not a direct sum of copies of the structure sheaf.  However, by Biswas and dos Santos, it is true if $\mathcal{G}$ is a direct sum of copies of the structure sheaf and we use the family of rational curves in a rationally connected variety as the covering family.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for your answer. Could you please offer me name of reference by Biswas and dos Santos?

Comment: Here is the link: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~joao-pedro.dos-santos/Scientific_publications/Triviality_criteria_for_vector_bundles_over_separably_rationally_connected_varieties.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true even for $\mathbb{P}^n$. For instance, the tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ restricts to each line as
$$
T_{\mathbb{P}^n}\vert_L \cong \mathcal{O}_L(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_L(1)^{\oplus (n-1)},
$$
and on the other hand
$$
(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus (n-1)})\vert_L \cong \mathcal{O}_L(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_L(1)^{\oplus (n-1)},
$$
however $T_{\mathbb{P}^n} \not\cong (\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus (n-1)})$.

Comment: how do you know about this property of the tangent bundle? It is unclear for me (sorry if the answer is trivial).

Comment: @Marsault Chabat It follows from tensoring the Euler-Sequence for $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $\mathcal{O}_L$ assuming that $L=V(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, then dualizing and noticing that $0 \to S  \to S(1) \oplus S(1) \to S(2) \to 0$ is the exact Koszul-complex for the regular sequence $x_0,x_1$ in $S = k[x_0,x_1]$.